# Replace Value in Dataframe Column based upon value in another column within the same dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace

I have a pandas dataframe in which some rows didn't pull in correctly so that the values were pushed over into the next column over. Therefore I have a column that is mostly null, but has a few instances where there is a value that should go in the previous column. Below is an example of what it looks like.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4HDJv.png)

I need to replace the 12345 and 45678 in the Approver column with JJones in the NeedtoDelete column.

I am not sure if a for loop, or a regular expression is the right way to go. I also came across the replace function, but I'm not sure how I would set that up in this scenario. Below is the code I have tried thus far (Q1Q2 is the df name):

```
for Q1Q2['Approver'] in Q1Q2:
    Replacement = Q1Q2.loc[Q1Q2['Need to Delete'].notnull()]
    Q1Q2.loc[Replacement] = Q1Q2['Approver']
```

---

```
Q1Q2.loc[Q1Q2['Need to Delete'].notnull(), ['Approver'] == Q1Q2['Need to Delete']]
```

If you could help me fix either attempts above, or point me in the right direction, it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html):

```
r=Q1Q2['Need to Delete'].notnull()
Q1Q2.loc[r,'Approver']=Q1Q2.loc[r,'Need to Delete']
```